# How to find if a sharepoint list was created from external content type?

Tags: 2010, development

Is there a method or way to know if a list was created using External Content Type with Sharepoint Designer? Something like:

```
list.IsCreatedFromExtContentType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SPListTemplateType` enumeration can be used to check if the list is an external list. Example:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
{
    SPWeb root = site.RootWeb;
    SPList list = root.Lists["ListName"];
    if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.ExternalList)
    {
        //
    }
}
```